# suppress comment "joining by..." when running dplyr::left_join

Tags: r, knitr, dplyr

This is probably straightforward, but I can't find the answer anywhere...

When I use the following code

```
library("nycflights13")
result <- flights %>% 
    dplyr::select(year:day, hour, origin, dest, tailnum, carrier) %>% 
    dplyr::left_join(airlines)
```

The following comment is echoed onscreen:

```
> Joining by: "carrier"
```

This is certainly useful info to see in interactive sessions, but when I use `left_join` as part of a longer script, I generally do not want to have this type of comment echoed (especially not when the script generates an html report through knitr, because that html will then also contain a printed `Joining by: "carrier"` line.

How can I prevent left_join (and the like) to print this comment?

Thanks, Peter

Comment: add `by="carrier"` to your code maybe?

Comment: Thanks @Khashaa, that works! (Feel free to turn it into an anwer, if you want.)

Answer (score 15):

The comment by @Khashaaa indicates one way to prevent the message, useful and succinct if you know in advance the binding variables. See `?dplyr::join` for how to do this with one or more variables. The syntax for the given example would be

```
left_join(airlines,by="carrier")
```

Because the `dplyr` code is using R's `message()` function to emit the `Joining by: *` message, you could use R's `suppressMessages()` wrapper around the `left_join` (or any other `dplyr` join) to suppress these messages.  See `?message` for more info.  The OP example in fact returns two kinds of messages,

```
>library("nycflights13")
>library("dplyr")
>result <- flights %>% 
+    select(year:day, hour, origin, dest, tailnum, carrier) %>% 
+    left_join(airlines)
Joining by: "carrier"
Warning message:
In left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y) :
  joining factor and character vector, coercing into character vector
```

One can suppress the first message with the `suppressMessages()` wrapper

```
>suppressMessages(result <- flights %>% 
+    select(year:day, hour, origin, dest, tailnum, carrier) %>% 
+    left_join(airlines))
Warning message:
In left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y) :
  joining factor and character vector, coercing into character vector
```

The second message is a diagnostic warning message.  See `?warning` for more information; there are several ways to handle this case.  One way, if you choose to suppress it like the previous message, is to add another wrapper,

```
> suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(result <- flights %>% 
+         select(year:day, hour, origin, dest, tailnum, carrier) %>% 
+         left_join(airlines)))
>
```

Comment: In addition to the above answer: even left_join(airlines, on ="carrier") results in the warning message. Unlike most languages, the correct syntax in R is: left_join(airlines, by ="carrier") instead of left_join(airlines, on ="carrier")

Comment: I arrived here trying to combine two tibbles with identical column names. `###_join` spelled out all the column names, which was a bit noisy. In this case, `bind_rows()` did the job and did not produce any warnings.

Comment: @bovender You should know `bind_rows()` is very different with `###_join`.