# Why do "Joining, by =" messages bleed through in Rmarkdown code blocks despite using warning=FALSE? Should I report as a bug?

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown, message, suppressmessage

A helpful sequence here ([suppress comment "joining by..." when running dplyr::left_join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168204/suppress-comment-joining-by-when-running-dplyrleft-join)) shows that you can suppress the message by explicitly stipulating the joining variable or by wrapping the whole dplyr block in `suppressWarnings` to get rid of this bleed through.

This is useful but I don't understand why neither `"message=FALSE"` nor `"warning=FALSE"` in an Rmarkdown code block header suppresses this message?  The message seems somewhere between a message and a warning to judge by comments on it elsewhere but I would have thought we should be able to suppress the message with one of those block options.

I do understand the logic behind having the message when `"by = "` is not specified and I do know about `suppressWarnings` but wrapping dplyr blocks in anything seems a poor fit with the useful tidyverse syntax.

Is this worth a bug report or feature request?  And if so, to whom: is the issue with how dplyr emits the message or with knit or somewhere else?

Comment: You should post a reproducible example.

Comment: Wow. Thanks Ronak.  I confess that at first I thought "Surely it doesn't need a reprex" but then I thought "No fair enough" ... and my first one didn't show the issue so I have discovered that it seems to be a side effect of pander.  
```library(tidyverse)
library(pander)
bind_cols(letters[1:6],
          LETTERS[1:6]) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  rename(lwr = `...1`,
         upr = `...2`) -> tib1
bind_cols(letters[1:6],
          1:6) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  rename(lwr = `...1`,
         numbers = `...2`) -> tib2
tib1 %>%
  left_join(tib2) %>%
  pander()```

Comment: Agh.  Ran out of time trying to format that.  Sorry, failed to format it again but I think if you cut and paste that into an Rmd file you will see what I mean with "Joining, by = “lwr”" bleeding through into the output which it doesn't without the use of pander.   That probably explains why I couldn't find more about this.  I should report to author of pander I guess.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best option is to set your `by` argument explicitly:

```r
tib1 %>% 
    left_join(tib2, by = "lwr") %>%
    pander()
```

Alternately, use `suppessMesseages`:

```r
suppressMessages(tib1 %>%
                   left_join(tib2) %>%
                   pander())
```

Comment: I acknowledged that both were possible. However, you may, admittedly I think only occasionally, not know the intersect variables on which you will join in advance so occasionally the first is not possible and I continue to believe that in the tidyverse grammar, the latter is ugly and both surely sidestep the point that this is either a message or a warning so should be suppressed by the `message=FALSE, warning=FALSE` arguments in the Rmarkdown block header, which they are if `pander()` is not used, but which suppression is lost of it is used.  I guess I should report it as a bug in pander.